# Application logs on the command prompt from where application is being launched

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, command-prompt

I have an MFC application and launching its .exe from command prompt. What I want to achieve is that I want to show any logs from this launched application on the same command prompt.

I have written this code:

```
AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), errorMessage, ((string)errorMessage).length(), NULL, NULL);
FreeConsole();
```

But this code writes the log at the next prompt like this:

> c:\Users>application.exe
>
> c:\Users>log line

Here I want the logs on the same prompt, like this:

> c:\Users>application.exe
>
> log line

I am stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program works just fine; what you see is the command prompt that `cmd.exe` has prepared for you already, because your program detached and ran isolatedly from the console. As long as you don't detach, your program will continously occupy the console window.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It's *not doing something*, so the way to do that is *not to do that* -- look for where your application detaches from the console, and remove that.

Comment: I could not find anywhere in my application where I am detaching from console.

Comment: Well, I found the solution to this problem. Use **start "" /w "application.exe"** to launch your application, so that it will wait for the launched program to terminate and show the logs as I wanted.

Comment: @SGP, you can also launch from a batch file. cmd will wait on GUI programs launched from a batch file without having to use `start /w`. Or just build as a console application, or call `AllocConsole` instead of `AttachConsole`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to implement logging via OutputDebugString function. It allows you to see easily the result in the debugger and you can see that text also without a debugger using tools like DebugView (once upon a time on sysinternals.com, now available on Microsoft's site)